# Random publish errors - org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not load an entity

Tags: 2011, publishing, broker

On our tridion server, we see publish failures occur randomly.
The error is always something like this

```
Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, 
Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-822659-66560, org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: 
could not load an entity: 
[com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta#component[publicationId,itemId]{publicationId=39, itemId=93357}], 
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: 
could not load an entity: 
[com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta#component[publicationId,itemId]{publicationId=39, itemId=93357}], 
Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-822659-66560, 
...
```

This error appears randomly - this means that at some point, we can publish a component or page, and get the error, and a few minutes after, we can publish the same component or page successfully.

Anyone has any ideas or pointers where to look to fix this issue ?

The broker database is an sql server 2008 db, tridion version is 2011 HR1 SP1

Comment: Have you applied all post HR1 pre HR2 hotfixes? They solve a lot of these errors. Even better - apply HR2 and post HR2 hotfixes.

Comment: I would need to check with the IT department which hotfixes are applied. I'll have a look in the different available hotfixes if anything would apply for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some time, we believe we found the cause of the problem.

The httpupload service was running on a VMWare server which hosted a number of websites, and due to some configuration problem with VMWare (actually it could happen on any virtualization environment), the server was under high memory usage even when the sites didn't use that much memory (see [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111025838/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/saponsqlserver/archive/2013/08/31/virtualization-overcommitting-memory-and-how-to-detect-it-within-the-vm.aspx) for more info on the VMWare configuration issue).

Once we have fixed these memory issues, the publishing issue disappeared as well.